# Convert a string array to a concatenated string in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Is there an easy way to convert a string array into a concatenated string?

For example, I have a string array:

```
new string[]{"Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries"};
```

And I want to get a single string:

```
"Apples,Bananas,Cherries"
```

Or `"Apples&Bananas&Cherries"` or `"Apples\Bananas\Cherries"`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A simple one...

```
string[] theArray = new string[]{"Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries"};
string s = string.Join(",",theArray);
```

Comment: Hey, I knew that really.  It's just very hot in the office today and I haven't had a coffee!  Thanks.

Comment: Although it feels a bit odd. It think it is more an action on an array than an action on a string so it would be more "natural" for me to look for such a function in the array class. But thanks, I did not know there was such a way to join a string[] (so no more for constructions)! +1

Comment: But it would only apply to `string[]`, not to any others - so it doesn't fit cleanly into the "regular" array implementation. But you could add it as a C# 3.0 *extension method* to `this string[]`.

Comment: Why should you only be able to use string[] and not any type of array. I think it would be possible to just use the ToString() method of the objects in the array (at least I would do it that way) so you can also Join arrays of integers, longs and even complex objects (even your own objects when implementing the ToString). I don't know how other languages solve this, but because it was not in the array class I never noticed it (and creating a for was quicker than doing research on the internet).

Comment: Then write a `Join<T>(this T[] array)` extension method ;-p

Answer (score 12):

The obvious choise is of course the String.Join method.

Here's a LINQy alternative:

```
string.Concat(fruit.Select((s, i) => (i == 0 ? "" : ",") + s).ToArray())
```

(Not really useful as it stands as it does the same as the Join method, but maybe for expanding where the method can't go, like alternating separators...)

Answer (score 9):

[String.Join Method (String, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx), it applies an accumulator function over a sequence.

```
string[] test = new string[]{"Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries"};
char delemeter = ',';
string joinedString = test.Aggregate((prev, current) => prev + delemeter + current);
```