# Building a string from List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, list

The `List<string>` has ("ABC","","DEF","","XYZ"), how can I get the string "ABC::DEF::XYZ" out of the List in C#?

### ADDED

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> {"ABC","","DEF","","XYZ"};
string joined = string.Join("::", strings.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(joined);
```

gives `ABC::::DEF::::XYZ`, not `ABC::DEF::XYZ`, how can one skip the empty strings ("") in a list?

Comment: God help the graduates of a university in which this question is homework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string array to a concantenated string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304981/convert-a-string-array-to-a-concantenated-string-in-c)

Comment: do you really want valid strings separated by double colons or all strings separated by single colons?  Your output example could be either.  It seems to me more useful in reconstituting the list if it's all strings separated by single colons -- that way you can get the empty strings back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
List<string> strings = ...
string joined = string.Join(":", strings.ToArray());
```

In .NET 4.0, you can leave out the `ToArray()` call.

EDIT: Based on your update that indicates that you want to *skip* empty strings and use *two* colons as the delimiter, you can do:

```
// Use !string.IsNullOrEmpty or !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace if more appropriate.   
string[] filtered = list.Where(s => s != string.Empty) 
                        .ToArray();

string joined = string.Join("::", filtered);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string result = string.Join("::", list.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray());
```

Comment: @tvanfosson - Did not see those; edited. I'm wondering if the question was edited after posting, since some other answerers seem not to have accounted for those either.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Join("::", strings.Where(item=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.Join( ":", list )` in .NET 4.0.  If you are using 3.5 or earlier, `string.Join( ":", list.ToArray() )`

Comment: The "or earlier" doesn't really apply because of the reliance on the Enumerable.ToArray method, which came out in 3.5.

Comment: @Ani - as long as the generic collections have been around, `List<T>` has had a `ToArray` method in it's signature.  So as long as you're not using .NET 1.1, you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at String.Join(), example String.Join(":",list.ToArray());

Answer (score 0):

Using `string.Join` with `ToArray` would work.

As [Ani said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012754/building-a-string-from-liststring-in-c/5012776#5012776), if you're on .NET 4.0, you could leave out the `ToArray`.

If you're *not* on .NET 4.0 but you don't want the overhead of the `ToArray` call, you could write a method to create a `StringBuilder`, append every item in the `List<string>` plus your delimiter (skipping the delimiter after the last item), and return the result of `ToString` at the end.

Comment: Interesting idea - do you think the overhead of `ToArray` is more significant than the overhead of a `StringBuilder` and then iterating through the collection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look at [The suggested method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160217/changing-element-value-in-listt-foreach-foreach-method)

post this you can simply do `string.Join(",", strings.ToArray())`

(replace the empty strings with ::)